# Mailchimp: unordered list with conditional merge tag blocks inside?

Tags: html, mailchimp

Trying to use conditional merge tags *inside* an unordered list, but my merge tags are getting automatically wrapped with a `li`.

What I expect:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    *|INTERESTED:Types:ES|*
    <li>item 2</li>
    *|END:INTERESTED|*
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What I get:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>*|INTERESTED:Types:ES|*</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>*|END:INTERESTED|*</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

In the final HTML I get empty `li` items, which messes up my layout. Any way around this auto-wrapping?

Tried to wrap the merge tags with an `*|IF|*` as per [this article](https://iskati.wordpress.com/2018/08/02/how-to-use-unordered-lists-in-mailchimp-with-conditional-merge-tag-blocks/), but getting same behaviour.

Comment: can you post the code that generates this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet of code that you've posted should work as a workaround:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    *|INTERESTED:Types:ES|*
    <li>item 2</li>
    *|END:INTERESTED|*
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I've sent a test email with the above and it worked.

If you are doing this inside a WYSIWYG, you'll have to save it in HTML mode. If you switch it to the visual mode, it will mess up. And if you go back and edit it, it will also mess up.

Comment: This is a pretty unreliable option, but looks like it is the closest to a solution.